# Facebook Javascript SDK - Invalid parameter?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create an event via the Facebook API; however, I keep getting this error:

> `#`100 Invalid Parameter

This is the code:

```
    FB.api("/me/events", "post", {
        name: "Test Event",
        category: 1,
        subcategory: 1,
        host: "You",
        description: "Details",
        location: "London",
        start_time: "2012-10-05 15:00",
        end_time: "",
        privacy: "SECRET"
    }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
           alert("Sorry this event could not be created");
           console.log(response.error.message);
       } else {
           alert("Created!");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have fixed the issue.. These are the parameters for creating events..

```
name: "Test event"
description: "The details"
location: "London"
start_time: "2012-10-05"
end_time: ""
privacy_type: "SECRET"
```